# Keep getting an error key about column in the csv while it exists in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to use this dataset columns : [CSV Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbQ0R9qR411WDTeK6bm0l8qJ_nSWZjZv/view?usp=sharing)
Using the following code, I am trying to get the max, min, mean, and standard deviation for some columns. Unfortunately, I have got some errors about the keys when trying the access some values where the code has no syntax error or logic I think and also the columns are exist in the dataset.

```
  # Get the maximum and minimum values for the load in order to be used in some constraints.
  max_load_pv = data.groupby(["Date"])["PVLoadForecast"].max()
  min_load_pv = data.groupby(["Date"])["PVLoadForecast"].min()
  mean_load_pv = data.groupby(["Date"])["PVLoadForecast"].mean()
  std_load_pv = data.groupby(["Date"])["PVLoadForecast"].std()
  max_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["DGLoadForecast"].max()
  min_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["DGLoadForecast"].min()
  mean_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["DGLoadForecast"].mean()
  std_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["DGLoadForecast"].std()
  max_load_wind = data.groupby(["Date"])["WindLoadForecast"].max()
  min_load_wind = data.groupby(["Date"])["WindLoadForecast"].min()
  mean_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["WindLoadForecast"].mean()
  std_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["WindLoadForecast"].std()
  max_load_bes= data.groupby(["Date"])["BESLoadForecast"].max()
  min_load_bes =  data.groupby(["Date"])["BESLoadForecast"].min()
  mean_load_dg =  data.groupby(["Date"])["BESLoadForecast"].mean()
  std_load_dg =  data.groupby(["Date"])["BESLoadForecast"].std()
  max_load_zonal =  data.groupby(["Date"])["ZonalLoadForecast"].max()
  min_load_zonal = data.groupby(["Date"])["ZonalLoadForecast"].min()
  mean_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["ZonalLoadForecast"].mean()
  std_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["ZonalLoadForecast"].std()
```

This is the error:

> calculateParametersOnedayAheadEachMonth(t, str(d) ,str(m) ,"2016")
> File "", line 29, in calculateParametersOnedayAheadEachMonth
> max_load_dg = data.groupby(["Date"])["DGLoadForecast"].max()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1416, in **getitem**
> return super().**getitem**(key)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 248, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError(f"Column not found: {key}")
> KeyError: 'Column not found: DGLoadForecast'

Comment: Please repost the error in a code block to keep the formatting.

Comment: The CSV file has spaces after some of the commas. Add the option `skipinitialspace=True` when calling `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: Or fix the CSV file to get rid of the extra spaces in the header row.

Comment: readData = pd.read_csv("Vector_Data_PV_BES_DG_Wind_Forecast_France.csv", sep=',',skipinitialspace=True) ?

Comment: yes. `sep=','` is the default, BTW.

Comment: Now after change, I've got : 

    raise KeyError(f"Column not found: {key}")
KeyError: 'Column not found: WindPrices'

Comment: There's no WindPrices column in the CSV. Did you mean `WPrices`?

Comment: As you are grouping on a single column `Date` you could then in a single statement aggregate each column using a specific function: min(), mean() etc using **groupby.agg** so avoiding all the repetition of the groupby statements. Then as required relabel the aggregated columns or use named agg.  See [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)